# How to animate UICollectionViewCell expansion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uianimation

I have a UICollectionView. When user taps on a cell I have to expand the size of the cell. I am doing this like this,

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        isExpandedMode = true;
        expandedPosition = indexPath.row;
        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Now I update the cell size in here,

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(isExpandedMode && expandedPosition == indexPath.row){
        CGFloat screenWidth = 568.0;
        CGFloat screenHeight = 293.0;
        return CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    }
    else{
        CGFloat screenWidth = 172.0;
        CGFloat screenHeight = 293.0;
        return CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    }
}
```

Now I want to apply animation to the expansion of cell, where to write this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your changes to be animated put them inside of a call to [performBatchUpdates:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates?language=objc)